# Difficulty in understanding a Join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, rails-activerecord

I have following method with a multiple join in a project I am working on. I don't understand what is happening here with | operator. Any explanation would be highly appreciated.

```
  class SampleUnit < ActiveRecord::Base
    def unit_code(code)
      joins(table_a: [:table_b]).
      eager_load(table_a: [:table_b]).
      eager_load(:table_c).
      eager_load(:table_d).
      eager_load(:table_e).
      where(‘table_b.code like ?', code) |
      eager_load(table_a: [: table_b]).
      eager_load(: table_c).
      eager_load(: table_d).
      eager_load(: table_e).
      where('sample_units.code like ?',(code))
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'm not experienced using ruby or activerecord, but this appears to just be an `OR` condition inside the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Left part of the `OR` will be always truthy (meaning, right part will never be evaluated)

Comment: Also, did you retype the code or copy/pasted it? You have a backtick instead of a quote.

Comment: I was completely wrong. Check the updated answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [`Array#|`, or a "set union"](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C).

> Set Union — Returns a new array by joining `ary` with `other_ary`,
>   excluding any duplicates and preserving the order from the original array.
>
> It compares elements using their `#hash` and `#eql?` methods for efficiency.
>
> ```
> [ "a", "b", "c" ] | [ "c", "d", "a" ]    #=> [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
> ```
>
> See also `Array#uniq`.

`ActiveRecord::Relation` includes a `Delegation` module that forwards the calls to a bunch of methods* to the result of calling `to_a` on that relation.

Of course, that means that it's not a single query, but two queries with results processed by Ruby code: for instance, that makes it impossible to fetch a huge rowset (i. e. larger than RAM) in batches. Making a SQL union in Rails is [awkwardly hard](http://makandracards.com/bonyiii/24302-activerecord-union-with-arel), but possible as well.

**Basically, all methods not defined on a `Relation` itself, but defined on `Array` and not [blacklisted](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2dc5566db500fa1a63b78d85e253ae7996577705/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L40).*

Comment: This should be the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I was completely wrong. This is not boolean OR, this is bitwise OR. And it makes all the difference.

Apparently, when you invoke it on two active relation queries like that, it executes both queries and produces a **union** of the results. (tested on the mongoid queries, not activerecord, but in AR it should be the same, I imagine)

Comment: do you mean even a is an empty ActiveRecord Relation it will be true ?